# ConTeXt: bad spacing when a formula environment is placed within a TEXpage environment

Tags: context, mathematics

I’m working on a project that requires intensive use of mathematics environments and TEXpage environments. I noticed that bad spacings appear when a formula environment is placed within a TEXpage environment, as if my setup `\setupformulae[spacebefore=none, spaceafter=none]` was useless. ***Is it a bug or just me doing something wrong?***

Here is my code:

```
\setupformulae[align=flushleft, spacebefore=none, spaceafter=none]

\starttext

%\startTEXpage

Puisque l'on passe d'un rangement à l'autre en effectuant une permutation de \math{n} boules, on a :

\startformula
\#A = n!
\stopformula

Puisque placer \math{n} boules dans \math{n} boîtes revient à prendre une \math{n}-liste d'éléments d'un ensemble à \math{n} éléments, on a : 
\startformula
\#\Omega = n^n
\stopformula

On peut ainsi calculer :

\startformula
P(A) = \frac{\#A}{\#\Omega} = \frac{n!}{n^n}
\stopformula

%\stopTEXpage

\stoptext
```

Here is what happens **without** the TEXpage environment (`\startTEXpage` and `\stopTEXpage` are **commented**):

[image: Without the TEXpage environment]

Here is what happens **with** the TEXpage environment (`\startTEXpage` and `\stopTEXpage` are now **uncommented**):

[image: With the TEXpage environment]

The page is indeed cropped to content but bad spacings appeared before and after formulas. Any explanation? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour on my machine: what I get, from running the example code, is the same spacing with or without the `TEXpage`s. I tried the version of `context` that shipped with texlive 2017, and a recent minimals installation (from 2017-09-27). So maybe this is bug in older versions?

Comment: Can't reproduce either, try updating ConTeXt and update your questions if it still appears.  For now voting to close as unclear.

Comment: **I updated my whole ConTeXt distribution and it worked!** Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 2):

You can backport the new spacing model to old ConTeXt.  It's not a good idea though.  It could well be that now I broke something.  Better [update ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone).

```
\unexpanded\def\startdisplaymath
  {\ifhmode
     \par
   \fi
   \bgroup
   \informulatrue
   \beforedisplayspace
   \setdisplaydimensions
   \startinnermath
   \begingroup} % less interference with upcoming a \over b

\unexpanded\def\stopdisplaymath
  {\endgroup    % less interference with upcoming a \over b
   \stopinnermath
   \afterdisplayspace
   \egroup}

\setupformulae[align=flushleft, spacebefore=none, spaceafter=none]

\starttext

\startTEXpage

Puisque l'on passe d'un rangement à l'autre en effectuant une permutation de \math{n} boules, on a :

\startformula
\#A = n!
\stopformula

Puisque placer \math{n} boules dans \math{n} boîtes revient à prendre une \math{n}-liste d'éléments d'un ensemble à \math{n} éléments, on a :

\startformula
\#\Omega = n^n
\stopformula

On peut ainsi calculer :

\startformula
P(A) = \frac{\#A}{\#\Omega} = \frac{n!}{n^n}
\stopformula

\stopTEXpage

\stoptext
```

[image]